# How to hold multiple type data in pointer

Tags: c, gcc, void, void-pointers

I am trying to parse a buffer that consists of many types of data.

For an example buffer:

```
void* buffer = "1111aaaa[another similar buffer][a second similar buffer]1111"
// Buffer is not actually a string, it is just to show (these are bytes that correspond different types).
```

I have the information about how to parse this file so far I have been doing `memcpy` to extract these values, such as:

```
memcpy(some_int, buffer, 4);
buffer += 4;
memcpy(some_char_array, buffer, 4);
buffer += 4;
// etc...
// So I am trying to parse the buffer like using a file pointer.
```

This is working for me for now, but I had some irregular behavior (might be just some other bug, it has been working fine until now).

So I made some research that pointer arithmetic in `c` is ill-advised (Although GCC somewhat allows it). So how am I supposed to hold and parse these data in c ?

Some questions here on SO revealed you can cast it to a char pointer just before incrementing the pointer(by certain amount of bytes), but won't that give an implicit conversion warning and increase the complexity of the code ?

Shouldn't it be allowed to increment a `void` pointer if the developer knows exactly how many bytes he/she wants to go forward ?

If not, how can I accomplish this in other C methods ?

**Edit1:** If holding data in a `char*` won't do anything else than helping me increment the pointer, can I just hold all the data in `char*` and `memcpy` from there ?

Comment: @John3136 However, the data is binary, rather than a string. If you are saying that it is similar, than my guess in Edit1 is confirmed, and my question answered. But I don't think my question is unclear about what am I asking.

Comment: The void pointer arithmetic does not exist in standard C. Use `char *` and memcpy. Use `int32_t` instead of `int` for example ...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for the advice, I do already use `int32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

If the lengths of your data elements are known and always the same, you can set up a structure and cast your entire buffer to that structure.

Example:

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t some_integer;
    char some_char_array[4];
    ... (some_other_member);
} my_data_t;

my_data_t *data = (my_data_t *)buffer;
```

Then you can access your data fields using `data->some_integer`, `data->some_char_array` etc. which I think is clearer and more understandable than moving a pointer through the buffer.